# PHP - Is there a way to save an uploaded file into web directories?

Tags: php, html, file

I am not english. Hope you understand.

Hi, I'm trying to save an uploaded file into a web directories, but I don't know how to do it.
I tried to google it, but i did not found anything, so I'm asking here.
Here is my HTML form:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="myfile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $filename = "??";
    $txt = "??";
    
    $file = fopen("??", "w") or die("ERROR!");
    fwrite($file, $txt);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: The way to process uploaded files is covered in the PHP manual and also a large number of tutorials online. Start with the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: In addition to ADyson's comment (and linked resources) keep in mind that using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is important.